# Rule of thumb to select some of the Gabor filter parameters in OpenCV based on image size

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gabor-filter

I'm using Gabor kernel on equal-area sized blocks of an image. Let's say each block is 36 by 56. I am using OpenCV *cv2.getGaborKernel* to get several filters, mainly by changing **theta** parameter, but I am not sure what values or range of values to choose for **ksize**, **sigma**, and **lambd**. So, my question is, is there any rule of thumb to choose values for these three parameters, based on the size of image (of course here by image I mean blocks of size 36 by 56)? In particular, if you want to apply Gabor filters on image blocks, rather than the whole image, where the size of each block is relatively small? At least are there any reasonable values to start with rather than just trying different values?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/14715 I found this very helpful. You can refer to it.